# OSGi felix get service

Tags: java, osgi

I have registered two services with two felix example:

In the ***first*** bundle I register one service with the code.

```
Hashtable<String, String> props = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    props.put("Language", "English");
    context.registerService(DictionaryService.class.getName(), new DictionaryImpl1(), props);
```

In the ***second*** bundle I register one service with the code.

```
Hashtable<String, String> props = new Hashtable<String, String>();
props.put("Language", "Chinese");
context.registerService(DictionaryService.class.getName(), new DictionaryImpl2(), props);
```

But when I get service references with code

```
ServiceReference[] refs = 
        context.getServiceReferences(DictionaryService.class.getName(), "(Language=*)");
```

the refs' length is **one** instead of **two**.

When I register two services which implement one interface in one bundle with code

```
Hashtable<String, String> props = new Hashtable<String, String>();
props.put("Language", "English");
context.registerService(DictionaryService.class.getName(), new DictionaryImpl1(), props);
Hashtable<String, String> props = new Hashtable<String, String>();
props.put("Language", "Chinese");
context.registerService(DictionaryService.class.getName(), new DictionaryImpl2(), props);
```

this method

```
context.getServiceReferences(DictionaryService.class.getName(), "(Language=*)");
```

can get two references.

**add infomations.**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.felix.framework</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

i use 5.6.1 felix version. i debug the source code ,in **org.apache.felix.framework.Felix**,
in line 3584

```
final Collection refList = m_registry.getServiceReferences(className, filter);
```

the refList size is two.

in line 3595

```
if (!Util.isServiceAssignable(bundle, ref))
{
    refIter.remove();
}
```

it will remove service ref which the last bundle register.

Comment: What is the problem and what is your question? I don't understand what you're trying to say with "wo just one refs, and why?"

Comment: @Erwin Bolwidt  update the question, i just want to get all service which resigter in different bundles

Comment: Did you make sure that both bundles are activated before you query the service registry (assuming you register both services in their bundle activators)?

Comment: @erdal.karaca yes , i am sure.

Comment: So, you can see that both bundles are in ACTIVE state when typing "ss" in the osgi console? Moreover, are both activators called?

Comment: @erdal.karaca i use Felix，when i typing lb ,i can see both bundle are ACTIVE。 Not both are called ,the first service registered is called ,analysis by log

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint in the start methods of each activator to confirm that they are started as expected?

Comment: yes, i am sure they start as expected.@erdal.karaca

Comment: @erdal.karaca add some info

Comment: @erdal.karaca i think i konw why , in ServiceRegistrationImpl line 530  BundleWire requesterWire = Util.getWire(requesterRevision, pkgName); this will depend on  export-package which the first service bundle register but i donot know how to solve it, or whether this sence is reasonable